# Google sheets: Having trouble with Wild card not working

Tags: wildcard

Is there a reason that the following formula would not returning a true even if the search range contains a match but with a space behind it?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Main!C:C, "*"&L4&"*")=0, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Im having trouble comparing two columns as the data entered has spaces at the back or other errors which keeps returning false.

Once I go and manually add a space behind the name in the search range match it would return true.

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(Main!C:C, "*L4*")=0, FALSE, TRUE)
This works for me.

Comment: Tried this one also, still getting a false return.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Main!C:C, "*L4*")=0, FALSE, TRUE)
```

This works for me.
[image]

Comment: Tried that and still getting a false. I have two lists, one on the main and another on a attendance sheet where there are possible matches. When i create that formula on the main sheet and search the range on the attendance sheet it works. But when i use the formula on the attendance sheet and search the range on the main it does not work.

Comment: Could you post a sanitized version of your workbook?

Comment: So im importing data from a google form, tied to replicate something similar but can seem to get it to give the same result as the original sheet. Which is leading me to think its something to do with my transposed data. This is also making it hard to share a copy. Il try and replicate it still.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jPcmlQPmAq5VDnPkgdNxFawMyCzQSYvJc5ioYNtc4I4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not sure if you would need access to the import, if so just request. Its just a bogus sheet

Comment: Albert, sorry but I don't have experience with google sheets and the setup is messy. If you look at most of the cells they have formulas like: 
=IFERROR(@__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE"""),"Jacques")
They are also setup with outlining so I couldn't even get sort to work properly. I finally saved them as .csv files and imported them into Excel. Then stripped them down to create a minimally reproduceable example. With a little clean up via VBA I got rid of the spaces causing the problem and the formula in the comment above worked. I don't know how to fix it in Google Sheets, sorry.